# Custom recipe for mgetty in yocto project

Tags: yocto, bitbake, recipe

I have tried to create a custom recipe, in Yocto project, for mgetty. But when I build my custom image, there are some issues that I cannot figure out.

This is my custom mgetty_1.2.0.bb

```
DESCRIPTION = "mgetty 1.2.0 recipe"
SECTION = "mgetty"
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=fd3b2e6132b4ff4cb475558807ded25f"

SRC_URI = "ftp://mgetty.greenie.net/pub/mgetty/source/1.2/mgetty-${PV}.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "6700f55a61f3a71ce7b882a0d0b82d19"

inherit autotools
```

And this is the error output:

```
ERROR: mgetty-1.2.0-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: mgetty-1.2.0-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is 
located at [...path...])
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: [...path...]
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'bit-32', 'arm-common', 'arm-32', 
'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'arm-linux', 'arm-linux-gnueabi', 'common']
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 8
| make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: [...path...] exit 1 from 'exit 1'
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at [...path...])
ERROR: Task ([...path...]/recipes-mgetty/mgetty/mgetty_1.2.0.bb:do_compile) 
failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2741 tasks of which 2734 didn't need to be 
rerun and 1 failed.
NOTE: Writing buildhistory
```

Did I missed something in my recipe?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using devtool if you are new to Yocto. So, in this case:

```
devtool add mgetty ftp://mgetty.greenie.net/pub/mgetty/source/1.2/mgetty-1.2.0.tar.gz
```

This will create a local workspace for you with the recipe and sources. Now, devtool should be able to detect some of the things automatically based on presence of certain files in the package.

But, for projects like this, you might have to make changes to the Makefile as well to make sure that it doesn't override the compiler and flags variables. So, in this case, make changes to ensure CC, CFLAGS, LDFLAGS is not over-ridden etc. (replacing = with ?= would be one way of doing it). Once that is done, use 'devtool build' to build your recipe and resolve any further issues.

Once you're done with the changes, please create commits for them in the devtool workspace and use 'devtool finish' to create patches for these commits and have them included them in your recipe. See:

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#sdk-devtool-use-devtool-modify-to-modify-the-source-of-an-existing-component

For more information, refer to the manual.